# Problems with mod_rewrite and 301 redirects from one dynamic url to another

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hey all, I'm having all kinds of problems with a bunch of apache redirects just now and could really use some help!

I'm wating to put in a 301 redirect for a load of urls from a client's old site to their new site in the following format;

Old - `page.php?pageNum_rs_all=0&totalRows_rs_all=112`
New - `page/sub?foo=bar`

The values in the query sting for the old site don't in any way tie up to any ids or references on the new site, I only want to match that specific request and redirect to the new page.

It feels like I've tried just about every combination of rewriterule I can find online but still nothing seems to be working. This is running on Apache 2.2.

The rule I started with (and keep going back to) is;

```
RewriteRule ^/page.php\?pageNum_rs_all=0&totalRows_rs_all=112 /page/sub?foo=bar [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is that RewriteRule can't see the QueryString. To get at the Query String, you need to use RewriteCond. See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for examples of how this works.

Comment: Cheers rich, I'd looked at the briefly before but hadn't fully garsped it, tried it now and it's working ok, now to go make all the other 300+ work!

Answer (score 0):

I've always tended to use use a series of 301 redirects in the following manner

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage /newpage
```